# My Dotnet application throws timeout error when deploy with AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have setup AWS AutoScaling as following:

1. created a Load Balancer and registered one instance with it;
2. added Health Checks to the ELB;
3. added 2 Alarms:
   CPU Usage -> 60% for 60s, spin up 1 instance;
   CPU usage < 40% for 120s, spin down 1 instance;
4. wrote a jMeter script to send traffic to the website: Tried different number of thread along with ramp-up time

What I am seeing was very strange.

I expect the CPU usage to shoot up with the higher number of users. But when I start Jmeter test with any number of threads, the Server starts throwing "Gateway Timeout Error' once it reaches anything more than 1000 concurrent users.

I tried:

- Increase idle time out and keep alive too, nothing worked.

I am at a loss to understand why CPU usage is so low when the website is in fact timing out.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would SSH into your application ec2 instance and use htop (or a windows equivalent) to see which services on your host are running high. If its your webserver I would especially look into the configuration of the web server you use and start there.

Also just a suggestion: you can see if you can scale horizontally instead of vertically if this issue only starts being applicable above 1000 concurrent users. There are alot of options within elastic beanstalk to spin up new instances when you see a high amount of traffic. Aswell moving some CPU heavy tasks to worker instances; aswell as cronjob tasks like sending notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I mentioned above I checked everything. Htop it analyzed the CPU and Memory usage, it was hardly 10% used at the time error thrown. The thing where I am confused about is where to locate the Elastic Beanstalk Nginx configuration file in Amazon Linux 2? As the directory  /etc/Nginx corresponds to the default Nginx server that has nothing t do with the beanstalk configuration.

Comment: You are correct /etc/nginx is where the configuration is located. Staged files are most likely in /opt/elastic beanstalk. On deployment it runs the hooks / copy env from inside /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment.